How to order bars in chart node?
I have 3 nodes creating messages independently, and a standard chart node. How can I define the order the contained values are shown in a bar chart? In my flow

[{"id":"9671de94.b316e8","type":"ui_chart","z":"670457b2.6ab53","name":"","group":"65a72644.483318","order":3,"width":0,"height":0,"label":"chart","chartType":"bar","legend":"false","xformat":"HH:mm:ss","interpolate":"linear","nodata":"","dot":false,"ymin":"0","ymax":"1","removeOlder":1,"removeOlderPoints":"","removeOlderUnit":"3600","cutout":0,"useOneColor":false,"useUTC":false,"colors":["#1f77b4","#aec7e8","#ff7f0e","#2ca02c","#98df8a","#d62728","#ff9896","#9467bd","#c5b0d5"],"outputs":1,"useDifferentColor":false,"x":490,"y":300,"wires":[[]]},{"id":"65a72644.483318","type":"ui_group","name":"Geräte","tab":"fe205248.f04ed","order":1,"disp":true,"width":"3","collapse":false},{"id":"fe205248.f04ed","type":"ui_tab","name":"Geräte","icon":"dashboard","order":1}]

the order of bars in the chart depends on the order of incoming messages. If I inject C, then A, last B, the chart is

and not A, B, C as intended. How to accomplish this?

This is about node order: Enforcing Node order, which has a comment: "That kind of goes against the general principles of flow-based programming. It is the flow that controls order"
